# Separate section of image traced and expanded

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, live-trace

I have just live traced and expanded an image and I am wondering if there is an equivalent in Illustrator to a lasso tool to separate the two images? I have circled the two parts of the image that I want to separate. I tried to use the knife tool but since there are no paths that intersect with what I want to separate I guess it wouldn't work.

I realise I could use the direct selection tool but that is not selecting all the paths that I want as the illustration is quite point heavy.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Lasso tool is in the stack with the Direct Selection Tool (the White Arrow) or the  tool shortcut is Q.